# '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key for plotting decision function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Plot the training points
    ax.scatter(Xtrain.iloc[:, 0].values, Xtrain.iloc[:, 1].values, c=Ytrain, cmap=cm_bright,
               edgecolors='k')
```

I am trying to run this code but I keep getting the `(slice(None, None, None), 0) is an invalid key` error. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: You should probably give some indication of what library you're using. E.g. matplotlib?

Comment: There isn't nearly enough context here for anyone else to understand the code. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .